# Forms Authentication and Ajax postbacks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, forms, authentication

I've tried looking for this problem but have not come across anything similar elsewhere. I have written a simple Ajax chat client for my asp.net 3.5 website. I use linq to store and retrieve the messages.

I use forms authentication and the standard aspnet user database provision using ms SQL server. The chat page with the Ajax controls is protected using the `<location>` and `<allow roles>` tags.

The problem is that users log in fine and navigate to the chat page, but after only a few messages, everyone is thrown out to the login page.

This must mean that authentication failed but I have no idea why. It must be some interaction between the Ajax postbacks. Unfortunately I can't debug so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it has to do with authentication? Couldn't it be something with the Session?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WCF for your web services?  If so, make sure you have aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" in web.config's configuration/system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment.  I think there's a comparable setting in classic ASP.NET AJAX but I can't recall it.

Without this, your service requests don't have access to Forms Auth, Session State, etc. so when your location tags run through the UrlAuthorizationModule, they see requests as anonymous even when they aren't.

See here for more details:

- http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-forms-authentication-sharing-for.html
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx